Bounds for means generalized to ratio of integrals
Despite not being sure about the origin, I found the following inequality for means in here, that is
$$\min_i \frac{|x_i|}{|y_i|}\leq \frac{\sum_i |x_i|}{\sum_i |y_i|} \leq \max_i \frac{|x_i|}{|y_i|} $$
My first question is about the origin of this inequality. I appreciate if you can give me the name of this inequality, or a way of deriving it.
My second question is whether it can be generalized to integrals, such that
$$ \min_{x \in A} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} \leq \frac{\int_A |f(x)| dx}{\int_A |g(x)| dx} \leq \max_{x \in A} \frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$$
Any help is appreciated.

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the compact interval $A$ and asssume that $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in A$. Define $r=|f/g|$ and $p(x)=g(x)/\int_{A}g(x)dx.$ Let $r(x_0)=\min_{x\in A} r(x),\ r(x_1)=\max_{x\in A} r(x).$ The asked ineqyalities are now
$$r(x_0)\leq \int_A r(x)p(x)\leq r(x_1)$$ which are rather obviously true. Of course plenty of generalizations are possible.

Thank you very much
